# heroku node.js error

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, heroku, heroku-postgres

[code](https://github.com/hopyhopy1/C-Bot/blob/master/bot.js) So, I decided to make a discord points bot using heroku and node.js but I keep getting this error:

> error: syntax error at or near "DUPLICATE"

I tried debugging but got no results so yeah... i need help.
what im sending to the sql postgresql database with javascript stuff:

```
'INSERT INTO points (Roblox_name, Points) VALUES (' + name + ', ' + amount + ') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Points=VALUES(' + amount + ')'
```

example{
amount = 322
and
name = george
}

EDIT:
raw application log [with VALUES(' + amount + ')' changed to ' + amount]:

```
2018-07-26T19:32:08.576609+00:00 app[worker.1]: Ready to serve on 1 servers, 
for 6 users.
2018-07-26T19:32:42.536398+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/bot.js:56
2018-07-26T19:32:42.536422+00:00 app[worker.1]:             if (err) throw 
err;
2018-07-26T19:32:42.536424+00:00 app[worker.1]:                      ^
2018-07-26T19:32:42.536425+00:00 app[worker.1]: 
2018-07-26T19:32:42.536427+00:00 app[worker.1]: error: syntax error at or 
near "DUPLICATE"
2018-07-26T19:32:42.536429+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Connection.parseE 
(/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:553:11)
2018-07-26T19:32:42.536431+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at 
Connection.parseMessage (/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:378:19)
2018-07-26T19:32:42.536432+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at TLSSocket.<anonymous> 
(/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:119:22)
2018-07-26T19:32:42.536434+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at emitOne 
(events.js:116:13)
2018-07-26T19:32:42.536435+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at TLSSocket.emit 
(events.js:211:7)
2018-07-26T19:32:42.536437+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at addChunk 
(_stream_readable.js:263:12)
2018-07-26T19:32:42.536439+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at readableAddChunk 
(_stream_readable.js:250:11)
2018-07-26T19:32:42.536440+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at 
TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:208:10)
2018-07-26T19:32:42.536442+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at TLSWrap.onread 
(net.js:597:20)
2018-07-26T19:32:42.629819+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with 
status 1
2018-07-26T19:32:42.738809+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to 
crashed
```

EDIT new error log:

```
2018-07-27T12:24:05.106369+00:00 app[worker.1]: { error: syntax error at or 
near 
"DUPLICATE"
2018-07-27T12:24:05.106409+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Connection.parseE 
(/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:553:11)
2018-07-27T12:24:05.106411+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at 
Connection.parseMessage 
(/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:378:19)
2018-07-27T12:24:05.106412+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at TLSSocket.<anonymous> 
(/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:119:22)
2018-07-27T12:24:05.106413+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at emitOne 
(events.js:116:13)
2018-07-27T12:24:05.106414+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at TLSSocket.emit 
(events.js:211:7)
2018-07-27T12:24:05.106415+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at addChunk 
(_stream_readable.js:263:12)
2018-07-27T12:24:05.106417+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at readableAddChunk 
(_stream_readable.js:250:11)
2018-07-27T12:24:05.106418+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at 
TLSSocket.Readable.push 
(_stream_readable.js:208:10)
2018-07-27T12:24:05.106419+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at TLSWrap.onread 
(net.js:597:20)
2018-07-27T12:24:05.106420+00:00 app[worker.1]:   name: 'error',
2018-07-27T12:24:05.106422+00:00 app[worker.1]:   length: 98,
2018-07-27T12:24:05.106423+00:00 app[worker.1]:   severity: 'ERROR',
2018-07-27T12:24:05.106424+00:00 app[worker.1]:   code: '42601',
2018-07-27T12:24:05.106425+00:00 app[worker.1]:   detail: undefined,
2018-07-27T12:24:05.106426+00:00 app[worker.1]:   hint: undefined,
2018-07-27T12:24:05.106427+00:00 app[worker.1]:   position: '72',
2018-07-27T12:24:05.106428+00:00 app[worker.1]:   internalPosition: 
undefined,
2018-07-27T12:24:05.106429+00:00 app[worker.1]:   internalQuery: undefined,
2018-07-27T12:24:05.106430+00:00 app[worker.1]:   where: undefined,
2018-07-27T12:24:05.106431+00:00 app[worker.1]:   schema: undefined,
2018-07-27T12:24:05.106433+00:00 app[worker.1]:   table: undefined,
2018-07-27T12:24:05.106434+00:00 app[worker.1]:   column: undefined,
2018-07-27T12:24:05.106435+00:00 app[worker.1]:   dataType: undefined,
2018-07-27T12:24:05.106436+00:00 app[worker.1]:   constraint: undefined,
2018-07-27T12:24:05.106437+00:00 app[worker.1]:   file: 'scan.l',
2018-07-27T12:24:05.106438+00:00 app[worker.1]:   line: '1087',
2018-07-27T12:24:05.106439+00:00 app[worker.1]:   routine: 'scanner_yyerror' 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to re-specify values in this part of the statement `Points=Values(' + amount + ')'`

It can instead just be `Points = amount`. Perhaps you'll need to `CAST` or `CONVERT` `amount` to an integer value, but that should be it.

Comment: yeah i got the error before adding the values bit too and cast or convert?

Comment: also, if(!isNaN(amount)) checks if the variable is an integer

Answer (score 0):

if **Roblox_name** and **Points** is string then value must be set in '*values*'

```
"INSERT INTO points (Roblox_name, Points) VALUES ('" + name + "','" + amount + "')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Points=VALUES('" + amount + "')"
```

and you should use

```
if(err !== null){
    console.error(err);
    return;
}
```

instead of

```
if (err) throw err;
```

Comment: thanks for your input but I've added both and still get the error

Comment: the log after I edited it is under EDIT new error log: in the main post

Comment: I do not know the syntax of DUPLICATE in sql, so let me ask here how you want to insert data, it can be replaced by another query.

Comment: It's meant to insert a value unless the Roblox_name value exists then it updates then it updates the value

Comment: If you specify update data if it exists, why not try using a select statement to retrieve "Roblox_name" if it exists, you can use the UPDATE or INSERT statement if it does not already exist.